# Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic hangs

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

On Ubuntu 20.04 Server, last time the upgrade process was interrupted. If I start the process again, I have to perform:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

But it doesn't finish this step:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
```

```
~# apt-get dist-upgrade
E: Der dpkg-Prozess wurde unterbrochen; Sie müssen manuell »dpkg --configure -a« ausführen, um das Problem zu beheben.
 dpkg --configure -a
initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.2) wird eingerichtet ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Trigger für initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.2) werden verarbeitet ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
```

Pleas help me solve the package problems.

Comment: What is the hardware of this system? CPU? Amount of memory?

Comment: I reinstalled the server